# Proving multiplicative property of euler's totient function $\phi$ using probability

Tags: probability, prime-numbers

If $m,n$ are co-prime , we know that $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

I want to prove it using probability.

Probability that a selected number less than or equal to $mn$ is co-prime to $mn$ = $\dfrac{\phi(mn)}{mn}$

Probability that a selected number less than or equal to $m$ is co-prime to $m$ = $\dfrac{\phi(m)}{m}$

Probability that a selected number less than or equal to $n$ is co-prime to $n$ = $\dfrac{\phi(n)}{n}$

How to define events and sample space and then how to prove the last two events are independent in-order to prove desired one?

Comment: It seems to me that proving independence is exactly proving multiplicativity.

Comment: What is sample space here ? Is it the $s_x=$ set of elements less than or equal to $x$ ?